# 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Tags: c#

I have a 3X3 array `byte[,] grid = new byte[3,3];` and accessing it works fine across my program but when I try to find the total of the lateral row through a loop I get an error  'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'. I know what it means but I don't understand why I get it.

```
        total = 0;
        for (byte xy = 2; xy >= 0; xy-=1) {
            total += grid[xy, xy]; //this is were i get the error
        }
```

Comment: `byte` is unsigned so it goes from `0` to `255`.

Comment: Byte is unsigned. So `xy - 1` would be 255 when xy is zero

Comment: `>= 0` should be `x > 0`

Comment: Because byte is unsigned, `xy` will always be `>=0`.

Comment: Changing `>= 0` to `> 0` will cause the loop to miss the last iteration, `grid[0, 0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going through the loop:

1st: xy = 2

2nd: xy = 1

3rd: xy = 0

4th: xy = 255

0 - 1 = 255 since your loop variable, xy, is a byte it can't represent a negative value, only 0 to 255.

To fix your loop you can change xy to be an `int`.  That way it can represent a negative value allowing the condition xy >= 0 to return false and exit the loop.

```
for (int xy = 2; xy >= 0; xy-=1) {
    total += grid[xy, xy];
}
```